# Prove $D$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $D:={\{}p+q\sqrt2:p,q \in \mathbb{Z}  \}$. *Prove that D is dense in* $\mathbb{R} $

I have the solution to this problem but I was wondering if there is another way to prove it.

*I remember seeing somewhere that a set* $A$ *is said to be dense in X iff* $\overline A = X$. **Does this (***sketch of a***) proof make any sense?**
*Let [a,b] be an interval, s.t.* $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ *with* $\pm \infty$ *allowed*.

Let $u_n := p^n + q^n\sqrt2$.  $u_n\in D^{\mathbb{N}}$ and then we prove that $u_n$ is not bounded above nor below, and since the only closed sets of $\mathbb{R}$ are closed intervals, we conclude that the smallest closed set (interval) $A$ s.t $D \subset A $ is $\mathbb{R}$, therefore $\overline D = \mathbb{R}$ ; D is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, $A$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $\overline{A}=X$. That is my definition of dense, which one is yours?

Comment: If your idea is to use the sequence lemma to say that every point in the closure of $D$ lies in $\mathbb{R}$ you're going in the right direction. 

The sequence lemma is the following: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequence_Lemma

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that was my idea, without being very rigurous about the proof. The solution proposed to this problem would probably not be the first to cross my mind if asked to prove that a set A is dense in X. In short it proves that D is stable under multiplication and addition and eventually proves that for any interval $[a,b]$ s.t $a<b$ there are $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t $mu^n \in [a,b]$

Comment: Oh, I've never heared about that, gonna check it later. However, I think there are some errors. Closed intervals are not the only closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$, the finite union of closed intervals is also closed. Do you know what Hausdorff is? Because $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff ($T_2$) which implies $T_1$, and $T_1$ implies singletons are closed, i.e. $\{x\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. You might say without lose of generality we take a basic element $[a,b]$ for example, or something like that.

Comment: Oh, yeah my bad about the ''only closed sets''. No, I'm not familiar with Hausdorff.

Comment: Oh, don't worry then, it's an axiom of separation, $T_1,T_2,T_3,\ldots$ are used to "separate" points, open sets, closed sets, a point and a closed set, an so on, it was to justify why a singleton is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. 

Then let's see it like this. Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $\mathbb{R}-\{x\}$ is the union of two open intervals: $(-\infty,x)\cup(x,\infty)$ which is an union of two open sets (since rays form a subbase for the order topology), is open. Hence, $\{x\}$ is closed.

Comment: Thank you anyway, I was trying to understand if my idea works in the first place. I will try to write a correct rigurous proof taking in consideration the points you mentioned.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help, I can't totally check if all of your solution is correct yet, but maybe with those ideas you can write a more rigurous solution, good luck!

Comment: Your argument looks very strange. $p$ and $q$ have become free variables, but they are bound variables in the problem statement. Your introduction of a closed interval $[a, b]$ seems to be completely irrelevant and the final step of your proof seems to be saying that an unbounded set contains $\Bbb{R}$, which is not so (consider $\Bbb{Z}$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\in\Bbb R$ let $[x]$ be the largest integer not exceeding $x.$ There is an old result that if $x\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ then $\{nx-[nx]:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is dense in $[0,1].$

For  $y\in\Bbb R$ and for $\epsilon>0,$ take $q\in\Bbb N$ such that $q\sqrt 2 -[q\sqrt 2]\in [0,1]\cap (y-[y]-\epsilon, y-[y]+\epsilon),$ and let $p=[y]-[q\sqrt 2].$ Then $|y-(p+q\sqrt 2\,)|<\epsilon.$

Comment: There is a short slick proof (that I don't remember) of that "old result" using complex calculus, that also shows that $\{nx-[nx]:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$. Take $r\in (0,1)$ and let $F(r)$ be the set of sub-intervals of $[0,1]$ of length $r. $ Let $S(m)=\{nx-[nx]:m\ge n\in\Bbb N\}.$ For each  $J\in F(r)$ let $P(J,m)$ be the number of members of $S(m)$ that belong to $J$. Let $U(m,r)=\max_{J\in F(r)}P(J,m)/m$ and $L(m,r)=\min_{J\in F(r)}P(J,m)/m.$ Then $U(m,r)\to r$ and $L(m,r)\to r$ as $m\to\infty.$

Answer (score 2):

The fatal flaw is in this line:

> the smallest closed set (interval) $A$ s.t $D \subset A $ is $\mathbb{R}$, therefore $\overline D = \mathbb{R}$

Not all closed sets are intervals, and therefore we need to be careful about which one we intend.

- If we intend "the smallest closed interval $A$ such that $D\subset A$ is $\Bbb R$", then that is a correct deduction from previous statements, but it does not imply $\overline D = \mathbb{R}$.
- If we intend "the smallest closed set $A$ such that $D\subset A$ is $\Bbb R$", then that does not follow from previous statements and is in fact false.

One possible red flag: your argument as written would show that *any* unbounded set is dense in $\Bbb R$...!